# Editing quickedit-label text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the text of the `quickedit-label` class.

```
<span class="quickedit" data-id="9917488">
    <span class="quickedit-content">
        <span class="quickedit-label">Label text</span>
        <a class="rename-icon" href="#" title="Rename"></a>
    </span>
</span>
```

I used the following code to get the text and pass it to a variable, then change the text and assign it to the element.

```
var labelContent = $('a.quickedit').text; 
var newLabel = labelContent.subst(6,9);
$('a.quickedit').text = newLabel;
```

I tried using `innerhtml`, `.data()` and `.value()` but all returned incorrect outputs.

I know this isn't correct (and the `newLabel` format is just for demonstration purposes) but this should outline what I'm trying to do.

Ideally, I would like to have this within a function where the `data-id` of the `span` I want to edit is passed.
Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery `.text( function )` method to do this work like this example.

```js
$(".quickedit-label").text(function(index, text){
    return text.substr(6, 9);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="quickedit-label">Label text</span>
```